# No indent for verbatim environment

Tags: margins, indentation, verbatim

I would like to deactivate the indent for the verbatim environment, such that left margin is the same for everything.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
 \makeatletter
 \setcounter{VerbboxLineNo}{-1}
 \renewenvironment{verbnobox}{%
  %  \setcounter{VerbboxLineNo}{-1}%
   \let\my@par\par%
   \def\verbatim@processline{%
  {\addtocounter{VerbboxLineNo}{1}%
 \@tmp\setbox0=\hbox{\@tmp\the\verbatim@line}%
 \hsize=\wd0 \the\verbatim@line\my@par}}%
 \verbatim\verbbox@inner%
   }
  {%
  \endverbatim%
  \global\def\@tmp{}%
    \addtocounter{VerbboxLineNo}{-1}%
   }
  \makeatother
  \begin{document}
   \def\tmp{\makebox[0pt][r]{\scriptsize\theVerbboxLineNo\ \smash{%
    \rule[-1.4\dp\strutbox]{1pt}{1.4\baselineskip}}\ }\small}
  NO INDENT SHOULD BE AFTER THIS 
  \begin{verbnobox}[\tmp]
   ADASFASFASF
  \end{verbnobox}
  NO INDENT SHOULD BE AFTER THIS 
 \begin{verbnobox}[\tmp]
  AFASDASFASGASDF

   \end{verbnobox}
   RESET LINE NUMBERS
  \setcounter{VerbboxLineNo}{-1}
  \begin{verbnobox}[\tmp]
   Reset Line Numbers should appear here
   \end{verbnobox}
   \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I have removed the thanks as well as your name since it is displayed in the lower right corner of your post anyway.

Comment: Your problem is that you have leading spaces in your `verbnobox` environments.  They are echoed in the output

Comment: [Crosspost](http://golatex.de/viewtopic.php?sid=087328522989caf2ced2bc51d006f5e5&p=76335#76335)

Answer (score 3):

Simply removing the leading space from your verbatim content takes care of the problem.

Normally, leading spaces in LaTeX code are ignored.  But that is not the case in `verbatim` style environments, where spaces are interpreted literally.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
 \makeatletter
 \setcounter{VerbboxLineNo}{-1}
 \renewenvironment{verbnobox}{%
  %  \setcounter{VerbboxLineNo}{-1}%
   \let\my@par\par%
   \def\verbatim@processline{%
  {\addtocounter{VerbboxLineNo}{1}%
 \@tmp\setbox0=\hbox{\@tmp\the\verbatim@line}%
 \hsize=\wd0 \the\verbatim@line\my@par}}%
 \verbatim\verbbox@inner%
   }
  {%
  \endverbatim%
  \global\def\@tmp{}%
    \addtocounter{VerbboxLineNo}{-1}%
   }
  \makeatother
  \begin{document}
   \def\tmp{\makebox[0pt][r]{\scriptsize\theVerbboxLineNo\ \smash{%
    \rule[-1.4\dp\strutbox]{1pt}{1.4\baselineskip}}\ }\small}
  NO INDENT SHOULD BE AFTER THIS 
  \begin{verbnobox}[\tmp]
ADASFASFASF
  \end{verbnobox}
NO INDENT SHOULD BE AFTER THIS 
 \begin{verbnobox}[\tmp]
AFASDASFASGASDF

   \end{verbnobox}
   RESET LINE NUMBERS
  \setcounter{VerbboxLineNo}{-1}
  \begin{verbnobox}[\tmp]
Reset Line Numbers should appear here
   \end{verbnobox}
   \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ Steven thanks for the reply. But I meant it differently. Everything should have the same margin. Now, the numbers are slightly shifted to the left. I was hoping for this: HEADLINE 1 1 some stufff 2 dafasf 3 aasfafas HEADLINE 2 1 some stufff 2 dafasf 3 aasfafas hope this helps :)

Comment: @Arjen Change `\makebox[0pt][r]` simply to `\makebox`.